# Do I lose the "High" or "Dark" modifer if I gain a race?

Tags: munchkin

The Reloaded expansion for standard Munchkin adds High and Dark modifiers to your class. If I get the High card without already having a race, I become a High Human. If I then get a Race card such as Elf, do I become a Dark Elf? Or do I lose the High card because I changed races?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both High and Dark say: "Add this card to a race card". In my reading this means that you can't be a High Human, and so the question is not applicable.

Comment: Hmm, you start out as a Human, but you're saying it's about having a race **card**?

Comment: Agreed. If the card says "Add this card to a race card", you can't be a High or Dark human. Similarly, you can't be a Super Munchkin with no class.